# AWS SES CURL ERROR

Tags: email, amazon-aws, ses

Estou tentando configurar um servidor de email para meu website, mas quando tento enviar algum email recebo este erro:

```
Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to email.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 443: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html
```

Alguém aqui ja passou por este erro e saiba como resolver?
Gratidão!

Comment: Qual linguagem usou para a requisição ? Coloque tambem o codigo que esta tentando utilizar

Comment: Estou usando laravel, ele ja me da tudo praticamente pronto, só instalei o sdk conforme está na documentação e configurei, segue o link https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido, era o servidor `us-east-2` que estava incorreto!